# AWS AURORA DB(My SQL 5.6) ver 1.22.2 Eclipse link jpa table data vanished (JAVA MAVEN )

Tags: mysql, maven, jpa, eclipselink, amazon-aurora

We are getting peculiar issue, sometimes two tables (parent and child) data is getting vanished or automatically whole data got deleted.
Please find the following configurations

1)DB Server ----> AWS Aurora DB (mySql 5.6) ver 1.22.2

2)Eclipselink JPA ----> ver 2.7.4

3)JPA mapping

```
@OneToMany(MappedBy="transactions",cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}
@CascadeOnDelete
@JSonIgnore
private List<ProductMaster> productMaster;
```

Entire Data is getting deleted from productMaster and transactions after doing some  CRUD operations.
We could not able to find out how its happening.

Note:-Last 7 years it is working fine with out any issue. If any common dependency changes in pom.xml, above issue will happen?

Comment: what data exactly and when is it data going missing - I don't know of any dependencies that would cause this, but what is the 'CascadeTypeOnDelete' annotation? That isn't an EclipseLink/JPA annotation. Did you mean to use EclipseLink's CascadeOnDelete?

Comment: its cascadeOnDelete , by mistake I typed wrongly... is it because of @cascadeOnDelete ?

Comment: It was running smoothly so many years... last one week its happening randomly.

Comment: CascadeOnDelete tells EclipseLink your DB has "ON DELETE CASCADE" set on the fk and will clear out entries anytime the parent is deleted without JPA having to. You'll want to track down all statements on the DB to figure it out - if the app was working fine, it could be something else accessing and messing with the data, and the DB itself can audit it. JPA allows you to do what ever you want with the data though, including delete and de-reference it, so it could be some previously unused code/data path is being hit in your app.